# Dynamic Javascript Form Validation

Tags: javascript

[image]Please bear with me as I am a beginner when it comes to JavaScript !

I have a dymamic form that pulls information from a database. For each line in the database there  is a new row of form fields and the select name incorporates the id from the database - this is all on the same form e.g

```
<select name="supplier<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>" id="supplier<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>" onchange="validatelink3(<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>)">

 <select name="STOCKACTION<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>" id="STOCKACTION<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>" onchange="validatelink3(<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>)">

          <select name="stockreason<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>" id="stockreason<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>">


<select name="creditaction<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>" id="creditaction<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>" onchange="validatelink3(<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>)">

    <select name="rejectreason<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>" id="rejectreason<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>">
```

Users are currently missing out data when they are saving the record and I want to prevent this, The save button saves ALL of the records in one go so some lines will be totally blank if they have not yet been processed.

If a user has started to fill in the row but not completed all the information for that record then I need to stop the form submission.

[image]

Comment: `required` attribute not helpful?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand ? Required attribute ?

Comment: [This here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) is a page on w3schools.com on how to use the `required` tag. It is one of the new HTML 5 attributes. Be aware that it will behave differently in different browsers.

Comment: That wouldn't work as there is 1 form with multiple lines from the database - the user fills out a line at a time. Is It possible to put a condition in e.g. - onchange - variable set to required for appropriate record number... not sure how I would implement though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/). I use this to validate my login and create user page of my website. Let me know what you think of it!

This is a great javascript tool that utilizes jQuery to validate different forms. Its really nice as you can have it validate several different things such as max and or min text length. It is very easy to implement because all you need to do is add the identifiers to the HTML element.

**EDIT:**

To avoid a link only answer, here is the code that could be helpful.

```
<form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate>
  <label for="question">Do you code? *</label>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="question" value="true" required /> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="question" value="false" /> No
  </p>

  <label for="languages">If yes, in which language(s)?</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="languages" data-parsley-conditionalrequired='["    [name=\"question1\"]:checked", "yes"]' data-parsley-validate-if-empty data-parsley-success-class=""     data-parsley-conditionalrequired-message="This value is required since you are a programmer!" />

  <label for="question">Do you eat dog food? *</label>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="yes" required /> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="no" /> No
  </p>

  <label for="why">If no, why?</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="why" data-parsley-conditionalrequired='["    [name=\"question2\"]:checked", "no"]' data-parsley-validate-if-empty data-parsley-success-class=""     data-parsley-conditionalrequired-message="This value is required since you do not eat dog food!" />

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.ParsleyConfig = {
    validators: {
      conditionalrequired: {
        fn: function (value, requirements) {
          // if requirements[0] value does not meet requirements[1] expectation, field is required
          if (requirements[1] == $(requirements[0]).val() && '' == value)
          return false;

          return true;
        },
        priority: 32
      }
    }
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/parsley.js"></script>
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is also a simple html file that could do something close to what I think that you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.democlass {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello World</h1>
<input id="test" type="checkbox" id="chk"/>asdfad
<form>
<textarea></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">asd</button>
<form>

<p>If the check box is check the thing is required and if the box is not check then it is not     required. So tell your form to only save the rows that have the box checked?</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
if(document.getElementById("test").checked){
    document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].setAttribute("required", "true"); 
}
else{
    document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].removeAttribute("required");
}

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does look a little intimidating at first but once you add the proper scripts all that needs to be done is add the appropriate tags to your HMTL element. If you'd like, I could give you an example of how I use it later this afternoon once I have access to my code that I have.

Comment: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/customvalidator.html - might be along the right lines but how can I adapt this as the select names are dynamic from the database. - I'd really appreciate it if you could take a quick look, I need something if one of the rows are filled in on the line but the others are not then don't submit but there are multiple lines on one form so a little baffling !

Comment: so your database contains the HTML tags that you wish to display? Do I understand your setup correctly?

Comment: Look at the select name and id in the code from the question, should give you an indication. I'll try and upload a screenshot if I can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66587/discussion-between-darksaint2014-and-emma).

Comment: Thanks, I have updated several more times to make it a better answer.

Comment: Great to hear. Your welcome. Sorry I was no longer of assistant